# Cell hidden bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, cell, hidden, collectionview

I try to hide my cell id in the match @ "56eae83ae3c9a04d398b4582", it works fine except that when I scroll I have other cell of my UICollectionView hiding, an idea? Thank you

```
cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"id"];

                if ([cell.statusContest.text isEqualToString:@"56eae83ae3c9a04d398b4582"]) {
                    cell.hidden = YES;
                }
```

Comment: Try using else with `hidden= NO;`, this happens thanks to the reusability

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write `cell.hidden = NO;` in cell class method `prepareForReuse`

You need go to your cell class (`CellClass.m` or `CellClass.swift`) if you using custom cell, or just create your own CellClass  and add code below. Also check your cell in storyboard, it must use this class.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    // Reset your data
    self.hidden = NO;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    // Reset your data
    self.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: llya I do not use prepareForSegue

Comment: @victorbill Do you use custom cell?

Comment: prepareForReuse has nothing to do with segues. Cells are reused, and you need to clean them up before the system can recycle them.

Comment: @victorbill this is method of cell class, so you need go to your cell class and  add prepareForReuse method. I edited my answer now

Comment: @victorbill Overwrite prepareForReuse: in your custom cell and reset everything (including the hidden flag).

Comment: @Eiko Yes I understand, but how can you write an answer? Thank you

Comment: @victorbill no, you need put this code in your CellClass.m or CellClass.swift if you using custom cell, or just create your own CellClass and put it in, and check your cell in storyboard, it must use this class.

Comment: @Mudriyllya It does not work, I put in my prepareForReuse custom class, MoodCollectionViewCell.m, but it does not work